# Tetrahedral mesh of unit square

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods

I've got a simple question: How does a tetrahedral mesh of the unit square $(0,1)^3$ look like?

Comment: There are 6 different non-isomorphic tetrahedralizations of the unit *cube*. See Fig. 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.01288) (Pellerin and Remacle, 2018).

Comment: Thank you! So, if I understood the section of the paper correctly, all the meshes are congruent, right?

Comment: No, in this context "non-isomorphic" or "isomorphism-free" means "*not* congruent".